# App.post returning empty set of curly braces

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm building an express.js application that just takes data from A mysql database and displays on the screen and I'm trying too implement an insert functionality so I can add too the database via browser, when I post the results too one of the route points I am returned empty braces and do not know why,any help at all would be appreciated.

Index.js below this is addCountries.ejs

```js
//brings you too add Country
app.get("/addCountries", (req, res) => {
  res.render("addCountries")
  console.log("hello")
})

//inserts data from add countries
app.post("/addCountries", (req, res) => {
  sqlDAO.addCountry()
    .then((data) => {
      res.render("addCountries", {
        addCountries: data
      })
      console.log(req.body.co_name)
      console.log("hello")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.send(error)
      console.log("hello")

    })
})
```

```html
<h1>Add Country</h1>
<br>
<br>
<form action="/addCountries" method="POST">
  <label for="cCode">Country Code:</label>
  <input type="text" id="cCode" name="co_code"><br><br>
  <label for="cName">Country Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="cName" name="co_name"><br><br>
  <label for="CDetails">Country Details:</label>
  <textarea type="text" id="CDetails" name="co_details"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

SQLDAO.js

```js
var pool



//creates pool based on database provided by project spec
mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 3,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'geography'
  })
  .then((result) => {
    pool = result
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })

var addCountry = function() {
  // returns new promise
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // function that adds too database
    var myQuery = {
      sql: "INSERT INTO country VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
      values: [req.body.co_code, req.body.co_name, req.body.co_details]
    }

    pool.query(myQuery)
      .then((data) => {
        resolve(data)
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error)
      })

  })
}
```

Comment: add country does not have access to the request object - you'll need to pass that in so that it has data to place into the db and that the db can return. If you look in the DB you'll likely see empty or no records being added.

Comment: in the sqlDAO.js or index.js?

Comment: Both, like this: `sqlDAO.addCountry(req)...` then `var addCountry = function(req) {...`

Comment: Okay it works but I dont fully understand why, would you be able too explain that too me if you dont mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass a reference to the request object to `addCountry()`. This is because the `addCountry()` function inside the `SQLDAO.js` file does not have access to the request object.

Right now, in `addCountry()` the `req` variable is undefined, so when the SQL statement is compiled there is no data to insert. If you look in the DB you'll likely see empty or no records being added.

By passing in the request object, it has data to place into the db and that the db can return.

Edit both files like this:

`sqlDAO.addCountry(req)...` then `var addCountry = function(req) {...`

There are two reasons this is necessary:

1. Inside your `app.post()` function both `req` and `res` are scoped locally to the function and are unavailable outside that function.
2. Even if they were pseudo-global, variables are only available within the module they are created within. So you must export that variable or, in this case, pass a reference to it to some other function within some other module.